# How can I apply the flash to pictures taken with expo-camera in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-camera

I'm using:

- `"expo": "~48.0.4"`
- `"expo-camera": "~13.2.1"`
- `"react-native": "0.71.8"`

... to build an Expo React Native mobile application. I'm using an EAS dev build to test on my physical iPhone 14.

My problem is that no matter what flashMode I use, at the moment the actual picture is taken, the flash disables resulting in a dark unlit image.  I'm using `cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync()` to take the picture. Any ideas?

I found one archived issue on GitHub where an author of the package recommended to '**not use flash**'. Surely that's not the only option here?

When I press the button to take the picture, I see the flash light up on the phone, and I see the preview image get bright, and then when I see the image that was taken it is dark. I expected the image that was taken to be lit brightly by the flash as it appeared in the preview right before the shutter fired.

Comment: I have the identical problem on Android. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @paddibr Still no solution yet, very frustrating.